# New drive does not boot after cloning mbr/partitions

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I cloned the MBR and both partitions of a drive but the new drive does not boot.   The Disk Manager shows these difference:

ORIGINAL WORKING DRIVE:
C:\Windows       Boot,CrashDump,Primary   Status:System
F:\SysRecovery   Primary                  Status:System, Active & Boot

NEW SSD Drive:
*:\Windows       Primary                  Status:None
*:\SysRecovery   Primary                  Status:Active

Unfortunately, I don't see any way of changing the new drive's status to Active & Boot, or why the new Windows partition doesn't show 'System' in the status.

Also, since ultimately only the new drive will be installed in the laptop, I didn't assign any letters to it.  Could this be the problem?

How can I force 'Boot' Status on the new drive, while its connected as a slave (USB2 to SSD cable)?

Answer (score 3):

If your laptop has a CD/DVD drive and you are in the possesion of a Windows DVD, I would suggest this:

Disconnect the old HDD from the system. Leaving the SSD connected. **This is important as you want to fix the MBR on the SSD and NOT the HDD.**

Boot from windows DVD, enter the installation. When on the screen where you need to choose language for windows press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>

You will now get a command prompt. When in the prompt type

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr

bootrec.exe /fixboot
```

This should set your SSD as the active boot device by fixing the MBR.

Further reading about this issue and source is available [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/17521-how-fix-mbr-through-command-prompt.html#post187758) (external link)

Best of luck with the operation ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not assigning drive letters was a good thing - I wouldn't worry about it.

Your best bet would be to create a system recovery disk on your laptop, then swap out the drives and put the non bootable SSD into the laptop.  Boot to the recovery disk and pick a windows installation (it should get discovered at CD boot time) and the recovery console should write a new boot record for the drive for you :)

Failing that, it may be worth trying different cloning software.  I have heard a few people complain that they have made drive clones that refuse to boot no matter what they try.  I usually point them to http://www.clonezilla.org/

Comment: Another app that I have had nothing but luck with is Miray HD Clone.   There is a free version available but I think it limits the transfer speed to 20MB/s.   The paid versions unlock different transfer speeds, but the free version works just as well as the paid ones..   http://www.miray.de/download/sat.hdclone.html